# Passing latest activity's result via multiple activities

Tags: android

Perhaps this is trivial for some people, but I haven't found an obvious solution yet. I have activity A that launches activity B with "startActivityForResult()".

In the normal case, I can get the result of B back in A just fine.

However, there are cases where (while in onCreate() of activity B) I need to call B.finish() and start activity B again with slightly different parameters, so let's call that activity B1. But even in that case, I need to get the result of B1 back to A.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are finishing an activity and restart it, you are actually changing the activity stack, it's better to use Broadcast Receivers in such cases. Find an example [here](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-local-broadcast-manager/)